# Querying firebase real time database using firebase package unknown input parameter Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I use `firebase` package for web version of my app and `firebase_database` for device version.
When querying a specific node using `firebase_database` the `.once()` method doesn't ask for any input parameter but `firebase` counterpart expects a `String eventType` input. I looked in the API docs but I couldn't find out what should be passed in..
What string should be passed in?
As always thank you very much for the help.

The `firebase_database` methods:

```
Future<DateTime> getFirebaseSyncDate(
      String cityDb, String regionDb, String countryDb) {
    // TODO: implement getFirebaseSyncDate
    return ref
        .child('Firebase Sync Date')
        .orderByChild('Sync Date')
        .limitToFirst(1)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      DateTime syncDate = snap.value['Sync Date'];
      return syncDate;
    });
  }
```

and the `firebase` version:

```
Future<DateTime> getFirebaseSyncDate(
      String cityDb, String regionDb, String countryDb) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    return ref
        .child('Firebase Sync Date')
        .orderByChild('Sync Date')
        .limitToFirst(1)
        .once('') //            <===   String eventType ??
        .then((snap) {
      DateTime syncDate = snap.snapshot.val()['Sync Date'];
      return syncDate;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`once` receive an `eventType`, one of the following strings: `value`, `child_added`, `child_changed`, `child_removed`, or `child_moved`.

In your case, I think it must be `value`

Check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#eventtype:-eventtype_1) for more details

Comment: Oh sure. I see. I didn't really look at this package as just a wrapper  for the javascript SDK so I never checked relative firebase docs.. Thank you so much for letting me realise it, and for the answer. I know nothing about javascript and having never read Firebase javascript docs,  `firebase` package methods weren't any familiar to me. Many thanks again. Cheers

Comment: I see than probably I'm also reading the value I want wrongly. Instead that `DateTime syncDate = snap.snapshot.val()['Sync Date'];` it should be `DateTime syncDate = snap.snapshot.child('Sync Date').val();`. Correct?

Comment: It should be `snap.val()` to get the data. `snap.snapshot` would be undefined here

Comment: Using `child`, it should be `snap.child('Sync Date').val()`

Comment: `snap.child('Sync Date').val()` throws an error:  `The method 'child' isn't defined for the class 'QueryEvent`. But `snap.snapshot.child('Sync Date').val();` fixes it. I guess there are some little differences between  `firebase` package and the javascript SDK.